# How can i sort by multiple field in terminal?

Tags: sorting, terminal, cidr

I'm looking for way to sort my list(CIDR notation of ip addresses) with linux terminal. My input list seems like this:

```
1.0.0.0/24
1.0.4.0/22
1.0.16.0/24
1.0.64.0/18
1.0.128.0/17
1.1.1.0/24
1.1.8.0/24
1.1.20.0/24
1.1.64.0/19
1.1.103.0/24
1.1.104.0/21
1.1.112.0/20
1.1.128.0/17
1.2.4.0/24
1.2.11.0/24
1.2.128.0/17
1.3.33.0/24
1.3.34.0/24
1.3.101.0/24
1.4.128.0/17
1.5.0.0/16
1.6.0.0/17
1.6.128.0/18
1.8.18.0/24
1.9.0.0/16
1.10.72.0/23
1.10.128.0/17
1.11.0.0/16
1.16.0.0/18
1.18.116.0/22
```

I use sort command of terminal but can't sort that like what i want (**First** i want to sort by **prefix** then by **IP address** ). After using sort command:

```
$ sort -t '/' -k 2,2n -k1,1n input > output
```

Output after sort command:

```
180.0.0.0/10
183.0.0.0/10
183.192.0.0/10
196.64.0.0/10
208.192.0.0/10
219.0.0.0/10
220.0.0.0/10
221.0.0.0/10
221.192.0.0/10
222.0.0.0/10
223.64.0.0/10
1.128.0.0/11
1.224.0.0/11
2.0.0.0/11
2.96.0.0/11
8.224.0.0/11
13.64.0.0/11
14.32.0.0/11
14.64.0.0/11
20.0.0.0/11
23.192.0.0/11   <---
23.32.0.0/11    <---
27.160.0.0/11
27.192.0.0/11
27.64.0.0/11
31.224.0.0/11
35.160.0.0/11
35.224.0.0/11
36.192.0.0/11
37.160.0.0/11
39.32.0.0/11
39.64.0.0/11
```

The problem is that is sort just by first octet. Any help or better way to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

i solve it like this. First change slash(/) to dot(.) then sort my list and reverse swapping from the last dot(.) to slash(/) to have output like my origin file.

Swap / to . with sed command:

```
sed -e 's/\//./g' input > output
```

Sort list by multiple field with sort command:

```
sort -t '.' -k 5,5n -k 1,1n -k 2,2n -k 3,3n -k 4,4n -k1,1n output > output_sorted
```

and at last change last dot(.) to slash:

```
sed 's/\./\//4' output_sorted > origin_sorted_file
```

Answer (score 0):

With `sort` from GNU coreutils version 6.10 and newer(*) you can just use something like

```
sort -t '.' -k 1,1n -k 2,2n -k 3,3n -k 4,4n input > output
```

The `sort` command will just ignore trailing characters in a field not being part of a number.

(*) note: 6.10 (from 2008) was just the oldest version of sort / coreutils I had access to.